# MS Access: How can I write the word "P&ID" in a label without Access removing the "&" symbol?

Tags: ms-access

It is just a label. I wasn't expecting it to think it was smart text. Obviously, I tried putting quotes around it.

Comment: Try `P&&ID` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to figure out how to select your response as the answer, but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Gord Thompson pointed out that MS Access does something weird with the & sign, and so I just had to put two of them... I couldn't find how to promote his comment to an answer, and so I am answering this, to close it out.